# Appending multiple Dropzone on click dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I want multiple dropzones only after clicking **ADD** button. Is it possible? then how?

I tried this. But not working

```
$(".image_upload .add_new").click(function(){

    $(".image_upload").append('<form action="/upload-target" class="dropzone" id="singledropzone"></form>');
});
```

My dropzone options.

```
Dropzone.options.singledropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 0.5,
    dictDefaultMessage: "UPLOAD IMAGE",
    maxFiles: 1,
    clickable: true,
    thumbnailWidth: 140,
    thumbnailHeight: 140,
    maxThumbnailFilesize: 0.5,
    init: function() {
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
        this.removeAllFiles();
        this.addFile(file);
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the page has been loaded you need to create a dropzone object manually, this can be done by creating an instance of the dropzone class, from [dropzone documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically).

js:

```
$(".image_upload .add_new").click(function(){

    $(".image_upload").append('<form action="/upload-target" class="dropzone" id="singledropzone"></form>');

    let singleDropzoneOptions = {
        maxFilesize: 0.5,
        dictDefaultMessage: "UPLOAD IMAGE",
        maxFiles: 1,
        clickable: true,
        thumbnailWidth: 140,
        thumbnailHeight: 140,
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 0.5,
        init: function() {
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                this.removeAllFiles();
                this.addFile(file);
            });
        }
    }

    $("form#singledropzone").dropzone(singleDropzoneOptions);

});
```

Note that if you plan on adding more than one dropzone instance using this method you should find a way to give each new dropzone instance a [unique id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), or select each new dropzone instance using a different selector.